# Angularjs send only JSESSIONID cookie not others

Tags: angularjs, cookies

We are working on a RESTful Webservice with AngularJS. 
We are invoking Restful web service which create a cookie using addCookie() method of javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse (yes before that do some business processing). Once the response is returned from web service
We can see the cookie under Set-Cookie element of Response headers. Please look into Response from browser developer tool.

**Remote Address**:127.0.0.1:8080
**Request URL**:http://localhost:8080/test-app/authCode/activate
**Request Method**:POST
**Status Code**:200 OK

**Response Headers**
**Content-Length**:0
**Date**:Tue, 26 May 2015 14:41:33 GMT
**message**:System activated the authorization code provided
**Server**:Apache-Coyote/1.1
**Set-Cookie**:auth_cookie_name=VckfCE; Expires=Tue, 26-May-2015 20:41:33 GMT; **Path**=/services
**success**:true

**Request Headers**
**Accept**:application/json, text/plain, */*
**Accept-Encoding**:gzip, deflate
**Accept-Language**:en-US,en;q=0.8
**Connection**:keep-alive
**Content-Length**:6
**Content-Type**:application/json
**Cookie**:JSESSIONID=A61316520C343254790F12AE03D13242
**Host:localhost**:8080
**Referer**:http://localhost:8080/test-app/
**User-Agent**:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.65 Safari/537.36

**Request Payload**
VckfCE

After that we navigate to other resource using angularjs  $location.path('/resource'). When this call get executed control goes to a javax.servlet.Filter and we try to read cookie 'auth_cookie_name' using request.getCookies() but only JSESSIONID cookie is found there not 'auth_cookie_name'.

**How can I enable AngularJS to send this cookies?**

Answer (score 0):

Your cookie response

> Cookie:auth_cookie_name=VckfCE; Expires=Tue, 26-May-2015 20:41:33 GMT; Path=/services

has Path option and this cookie is limited to this prefix.
As a result "auth_cookie_name" is not sent in $location.path('/resource'), because "/resource" doesn't start with "services".

Comment: After setting up correct path problem is fixed! Thanks!